# Extending and filtering C# arrays

Tags: c#

I have been doing a lot of `List<SomeType>` - > `SomeType[]` conversion lately, especially when I'm filtering or extending arrays.

For example filtering:

```
// filter the list
var memberList = new List<MemberType>();
foreach (var member in members)
{
    if (member.someProperty != sentinalValue)
    {
        memberList.Add(member);
    }
}
// overwrite the old array with a new on dimensioned correctly
members = new MemberType[memberList.Count];
memberList.CopyTo(members);
```

or extending:

```
// create the new member
var newMember = new MemeberType();
// create a new array to hold the extended members
newMembers = new MemberType[members.Length + 1];
// copy over the old members
members.CopyTo(newMembers, 0);
// add the new member
newMembers[members.Length] = newMember;
// overwrite old array with new array containing new member
members = newMembers;
```

I have to use arrays (MemberType[]) instead of a nice generic collection because of the XML Serialization classes we use. I feel confident there is a nicer way to do this simple sort of thing so if you know of one (that doesn't add undue complexity) let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
members = memberList.Where(m => m.someProperty != sentinelValue).ToArray();

members = members.Concat(new[] { newMember }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Cheers, I was pretty sure Linq was what I wanted to use - I just didn't realize it was possible on arrays using extension methods. I should have read through the available methods shown in intellisense and found what I was looking for, but stackoverflow was even faster than that on this particular question.

Answer (score 5):

There are extension methods to do exactly what you've described:

```
var membersList = members.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `List<T>` class provides a `ToArray()` method which returns the list items as an array. Also as a side not in case you are using .NET 3.5 you can use Linq do shorten your filter code to effectively this:

```
members = members.Where(m => m.someProperty != sentinalValue).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Linq to the rescue!

Filtering:

```
members = members.Where(m => m.someProperty != sentinalValue).ToArray();
```

Extending:

```
members = members.Concat(new [] {newMember}).ToArray();
```

Comment: I think your members.Concat(newMember) example is incorrect. I get a complaint from the compiler - based on Domenic's answer I think I need to use members.Concat(new[] { newMember }) since Concat expects an array and not a single instance.

Comment: @James - Yes, you're right.  Thanks for the catch. I'll fix the answer

Answer (score 1):

Besides what others have already pointed out, there is also System.Array.Resize() if you want to skip the convert-to-List step.

But seriously, your XML serialization classes need to be thrown away and rewritten.

Comment: The XML Serialization classes are generated by XSD.exe